# Using RedShift CURSOR to insert and iterate

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, database-cursor

I recently found that RedShift supports CURSOR, and more specifically it supports the commands: [DECLARE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html) & [FETCH](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/fetch.html).
I managed to create a cursor and fetch some of its rows but didn't find a way to:

1. Insert the fetched results into neither table or variable.
2. Iterate over the rows of the declared cursor in a dynamic fashion (based on while or any logical test)

I didn't find any documentation on Amazon on how to do that, does someone know if that is even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this by creating a stored procedure which supports variables. You can read a dataset iterate through it and perform your logic.

The following example shows a procedure with output arguments. Arguments are input (IN), input and output (INOUT), and output (OUT).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp2(f1 IN int, 
f2 INOUT varchar(256), out_var OUT varchar(256))

AS $$
DECLARE
  loop_var int;
BEGIN
  IF f1 is null OR f2 is null THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'input cannot be null';
  END IF;
  DROP TABLE if exists my_etl;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE my_etl(a int, b varchar);
    FOR loop_var IN 1..f1 LOOP
        insert into my_etl values (loop_var, f2);
        f2 := f2 || '+' || f2;
    END LOOP;
  SELECT INTO out_var count(*) from my_etl;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


call test_sp2(2,'2019');

         f2          | column2
---------------------+---------
 2019+2019+2019+2019 | 2
(1 row)
```

source - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't have variables. Inserting into another table easier and much faster with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

If I understand your second use case, I don't know of any relational database which supports that behaviour.  You can filter the cursor when you create it, but once it is created your options are getting the next row or closing the cursor.  If you need to filter then you can `DECLARE` a new cursor.